# Averaging a number over multiple rows, selected by day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing up a statistics script for a service I run. I want to work out the average number of rows per day on a last 3 days, weekly, monthly and yearly basis. My basic thought is something like this to grab the average:

```
<?php
function getDayNumber($day)
{
    $start = strtotime("last monday");
    $q = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM mytable WHERE dayname(datetime) = "%s" AND unix_timestamp(datetime) > %s",$day,$start));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    return $row['count'];
}

$monday = getDayNumber("Monday");
$tuesday = getDayNumber("Tuesday");
$wednesday = getDayNumber("Wednesday");
$thursday = getDayNumber("Thursday");
$friday = getDayNumber("Friday");

$average = ($monday+$tuesday+$wednesday+$thursday+$friday)/5;

?>
```

The above is just psuedo code written from my head. I can't think of a better method though.

Is this possible to do via nested/joined queries? I'll need to be able to do it on a daily, weekly, monthly... etc basis. I figure if I can find a way to pull all the data in MySQL, I can just add all the *count(*)*'s together and divide them via the number of responses.

Is this feasible?

Any help is appreciated - thanks all!

Comment: Probably, adding example data with expected results would help

Comment: Sorry, what type of data do you want? The data in the table is irrelevant, right? I just want to grab the counts and average them based on the day. There's a field in there called "datetime" which is a standard date/time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding the date range for each data set then running your query. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the average number of rows that were created
 * during the given date range.
 * 
 * @param  string    $range    The date range to look for
 * @return integer             The average number of rows created in the given range
 */
function getAverageRows($range)
{
    $date_begin = null;
    $date_end   = null;

    switch($range)
    {
        case 'year':
            // Calculate the beginning and end datetime of the past year
            $date_begin = FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR . ' 00:00:00';
            $date_end   = LAST_DAY_OF_YEAR  . ' 23:59:59';
        break;

        case 'month':
            // Calculate the beginning and end datetime of the past month
            $date_begin = FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH . ' 00:00:00';
            $date_end   = LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH  . ' 23:59:59';
        break;

        case 'week':
            // Calculate the beginning and end datetime of the past week
            $date_begin = FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK . ' 00:00:00';
            $date_end   = LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK  . ' 23:59:59';
        break;

        default:
            // Calculate the beginning and end datetime of the past three days
            $date_begin = SEVENTY_SIX_HOURS_AGO;
            $date_end   = now();
        break;
    }

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE datetime >= '{$date_begin}' AND datetime <= '{$date_end}'";

    // Get and return query results
}

echo "Average Rows:<br/>";
echo "Past three days: " . getAverageRows()        . "<br/>";
echo "Past week: "       . getAverageRows('week')  . "<br/>";
echo "Past Month: "      . getAverageRows('month') . "<br/>";
echo "Past Year: "       . getAverageRows('year')  . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm fully understand how this works.

The constants you're using, I'm guessing they're defined elsewhere?

Also, how does this grab averages? From what I can see, this will just grab the total row count between those periods. I need to work out the average row count over the given period of time.